# Read line by line from text file

Tags: python

I have this text file that contains:

```
Ryan#Male#Ryan123#Ryan321#
Lina#Female#Lina123#Lina321#
```

the order is `Name#Gender#username#password`.

```
user = username.get() //from tkinter entry
pass = password.get()
counter = IntVar()
counter = 0

file = open("user.txt", "r")
for login in file:
     login = login .split('#')
     if user == login [2]:
         counter += 1
     if pass== login [3]:
         counter += 1

file.close()

if counter == 2:
     //go to next page
else:
     print "wrong username or password!"
```

this works, but, when I tried to print login[2], it returned;

```
Ryan123
Lina123
```

and when I used `Ryan` as username, I still can login using `Lina`'s password aswell. How can I make it check the content in .txt file row per row?

I mean like, check this row first:

```
Ryan#Male#Ryan123#Ryan321#
```

and when the login info is not found, it will proceed to next row.

Comment: probably unrelated: your indentation is wrong in the for loop, kick `login = login .split('#')` in by one tab

Comment: yep, you are checking two different fields possibly lying on two different lines (e.g. the user matches Ryan and the password matches Lina's). Normally user and password must both match for a single given user

Comment: be careful, `pass` is a python keyword.

Comment: I would not recommend storing a username and password in plaintext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password problem is because you never reset counter between lines. But it can be done even more simply without counting conditions:

```
file = open("user.txt", "r")
for login in file:
    login = login.split('#')
    if user == login[2] and password == login[3]:
        print 'Correct username/password'
        break
else:
    print 'Invalid username/password'
```

`pass`, by the way, is a keyword in Python, so it's a good idea to use something else for your variable name.

Comment: yes, i just changed the `pass` into something else. this is easy to understand and very effective . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an "and" condition here, since password and username should match!

```
he_is_cool = False
for login in file:
     login = login .split('#')
     if user == login [2] and pass== login [3]:
         he_is_cool = True
         break

file.close()

if he_is_cool:
     //go to next page
else:
     print "wrong username or password!"
```

Note that `break` will "kill" your loop, when you have identified the user. The program will also work without `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking two different fields possibly lying on two different lines (e.g. the user matches Ryan and the password matches Lina's).

Normally user and password must both match for a single given user.

So you can get rid of the counters and try with

```
pwd = password.get()
with open("user.txt", "r") as file:
    for login in file:
        login = login .split('#')
        if user == login[2] and pwd == login[3]:
            pass # go to next page, substitute pass on this line!
    else:
        print "wrong username and password!"
```

Comment: I believe you want `break`, not `pass`. EDIT: I understand why you used `pass` now. Still, I would recommend that you break out of the loop and let the file close properly before redirecting to a new page. (Also, your comment syntax is wrong. Python uses `#` for single line comments.)

Comment: @pzp nope, sorry. I used pass after the comment, I mean substitute with code to `go the next page` directly. Edited better now. Thank you